# How to start an email app via intent?

Tags: android, email

I try this:

```
Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{cif.email});
context.startActivity(intentEmail);
```

But shows selection dialog with unnecessary applications (google drive and other). How i can fix it?

Comment: add `intentEmail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the data as "mailto:", if you want it to send to a specific email you can specify by saying "mailto:email@email.com"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + some email)); // or just "mailto:"
startActivity(intent);
```

Good Luck!